# Connecting to database through python

Tags: python, popen

I am connecting Oracle in python through subprocess Here I am trying to provide the input through console and get the output from db from table all_db_links I am getting no result in this code, not even a error. What could be wrong in it ? Thanks already :)

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE 
value = raw_input()

def runSqlQuery (sqlCommand, connectString): 
    session = Popen(['sqlplus', '-S', connectString], 
    stdin = PIPE, 
    stdout= PIPE, 
    stderr = PIPE) 

    session.stdin.write(sqlCommand)
    return session.communicate()

connectString = 'user/pwd@db' sqlCommand =""" SET HEADING OFF ( select * from all_db_links where OWNER ='?' , (value))"""
outcome = runSqlQuery (sqlCommand connectString) for i in outcome: print(i)
```

Comment: No need to use subprocess hen you have modules which do this for you. Have a look here: [cx_Oracle](https://oracle.github.io/python-cx_Oracle)

Comment: Thanks Valentino for the response, I am using 2.6.6 version of python in the production env , unfortunately due to some constraints in my company unable to install cx_Oracle module, version upgrade also is not possible , hence I am using subprocess.